# Using getopt in C with non-option arguments

Tags: c, arguments, argv, getopt, getopt-long

I'm making a small program in C that deals with a lot of command line arguments, so I decided to use getopt to sort them for me.

However, I want two non-option arguments (source and destination files) to be mandatory, so you have to have them as arguments while calling the program, even if there's no flags or other arguments.

Here's a simplified version of what I have to handle the arguments with flags:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:d:btw:h:s:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'i': {
            i = (int)atol(optarg);
        }
        case 'd': {
            d = (int)atol(optarg);
        }
        case 'b':
            buf = 1;
            break;
        case 't':
            time = 1;
            break;
        case 'w':
            w = (int)atol(optarg);
            break;
        case 'h':
            h = (int)atol(optarg);
            break;
        case 's':
            s = (int)atol(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

How do I edit this so that non-option arguments are also handled?

I also want to be able to have the non-options either before *or* after the options, so how would that be handled?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`getopt` sets the `optind` variable to indicate the position of the next argument.

Add code similar to this **after** the options loop:

```
if (argv[optind] == NULL || argv[optind + 1] == NULL) {
  printf("Mandatory argument(s) missing\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to allow options after regular arguments you can do something similar to this:

```
while (optind < argc) {
  if ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:d:btw:h:s:")) != -1) {
    // Option argument
    switch (c) {
        case 'i': {
            i = (int)atol(optarg);
        }
        case 'd': {
            d = (int)atol(optarg);
        }
        case 'b':
            buf = 1;
            break;
        case 't':
            time = 1;
            break;
        case 'w':
            w = (int)atol(optarg);
            break;
        case 'h':
            h = (int)atol(optarg);
            break;
        case 's':
            s = (int)atol(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    else {
        // Regular argument
        <code to handle the argument>
        optind++;  // Skip to the next argument
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but my loop will exit if the mandatory arguments come before the optional ones, so only the mandatory ones will be processed and not the optional ones. How do i fix this?

Comment: It is common to require that options come before arguments. Just specify it in the `man` page.

Comment: Yeah I know but for example with the ssh command, the -p flag can come either before *or* after the mandatory username@server argument. I just wanna know how to do that

Comment: @Conor I've added an outline on how to do it, see the edit above.

Comment: Your edit code was very helpful, thanks. A little silly that I have to force continued parsing by micro-managing a global variable, but it gets the job done!

Comment: Should check that `argc > optind` before accessing `argv[optind]`!

Comment: @gatopeich `argv[argc]` is guaranteed by the C standard to be `NULL`, so the code I provided should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. Still it is strictly safer and more efficient to compare `argc` with `optind`: `if ( optind+2 > argc) { <missing 2 arguments> }`.

Comment: The example you provided under EDIT clearly doesn't work (at least on Linux), I can't believe nobody has noticed that since this was first posted.

Comment: Is this a ChatGPT answer? The `else` clause follows `switch` *(not an `if`)*, the indentation is screwed up because the closing parentheses of `if` is aligned to where `while` closing parentheses supposed to be; the `while` closing parentheses is absent completely; and on top of that, the code in `EDIT` couldn't possibly work even if fixed *(and I tested that)*, because [per `getopt` documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html#RETURN_VALUE) `-1` is only returned if *everything* has been parsed, which is unrelated to the presence of dash inside an arg.

Comment: The code doesn't work. How could this be an accepted answer?

Answer (score 17):

Really good example could be found here: [GNU Libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt) The code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
int aflag = 0;
int bflag = 0;
char *cvalue = NULL;
int index;
int c;

opterr = 0;

while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
switch (c)
{
case 'a':
    aflag = 1;
    break;
case 'b':
    bflag = 1;
    break;
case 'c':
    cvalue = optarg;
    break;
case '?':
    if (optopt == 'c')
    fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
    else if (isprint (optopt))
    fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
    else
    fprintf (stderr,
        "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
        optopt);
    return 1;
default:
    abort ();
}

printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cvalue = %s\n",
    aflag, bflag, cvalue);

for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
return 0;
}
```

It allows to have options before and after arguments. I did compile and run test example:

```
$ ./a.out aa ff bb -a -ctestparam hello
aflag = 1, bflag = 0, cvalue = testparam
Non-option argument aa
Non-option argument ff
Non-option argument bb
Non-option argument hello
```

Comment: This does not work using Mac OSX's version of getopt.

Comment: in linux glibc, optind will points to mandatory arguments even they are behind options after getopt()

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html

> By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans,
> so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.  Two other
> scanning modes are also implemented.  If the first character of
> optstring is '+' or the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is
> set, then option processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument
> is encountered.  If the first character of optstring is '-', then
> each nonoption argv-element is handled as if it were the argument
> of an option with character code 1.  (This is used by programs
> that were written to expect options and other argv-elements in
> any order and that care about the ordering of the two.)  The
> special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning regardless
> of the scanning mode.

Comment: While your citation may inform about the issue at hand, pls. elaborate on your answer to address the question "How do I edit this so that non-option arguments are also handled?"

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    
  char* inputfile;
  char* outputfile;
  char* output_file_type;
  char* color_red;
  char* color_blue;
  char* color_green;
  
  
  int opt;
  
  if (argv[optind] == NULL || argv[optind + 1] == NULL) {
  printf("Mandatory argument(s) missing\n");
  exit(1);
    }
 
  
  while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":i:o:r:g:b:t:")) != -1){
    switch(opt){
      case 'i':
        inputfile = optarg;
        printf("Input file : %s\n",inputfile);
        break;  
      case 'o':
        outputfile = optarg;
        printf("Output File: %s\n",outputfile);
        break;
      case 't':
        output_file_type = optarg;
        printf("Output File type: %s\n", output_file_type);
        break;
      case 'r':
        color_red = optarg;
        printf("Color Red: %s\n",color_red);
        break;
      case 'g':
        color_green = optarg;
        printf("Color Green: %s\n",color_green);
        break;
      case 'b':
        color_blue = optarg;
        printf("Color Blue: %s\n",color_blue);
        break;
      case ':':
        printf("option needs a value\n");
        break;
      case '?':
        printf("unknown option: %c\n", optopt);
        break;
    }
  
  }
  
  for (; optind < argc; optind++){
      
      
       printf("Given extra arguments: %s\n", argv[optind]);
     
   
  }  


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Run commands:

```
gcc main.c -o image
./image -i ./resource/input_file.bmp -o ./resource/output_file.bmp -t BPM -r 10 -g 24 -b 40
```

output:

```
Input file : ./resource/input_file.bmp
Output File: ./resource/output_file.bmp
Output File type: BPM
Color Red: 10
Color Green: 24
```

Answer (score 0):

The author of [Mead's Guide to getopt](https://azrael.digipen.edu/%7Emmead/www/mg/getopt/index.html) states

> If you want to have getopt parse and return the non-option arguments in the while loop (in the order specified), you must direct it to do so by putting a minus (-) in front of the optstring.

The example provided was "-:a:b:X" where the minus (-) "disables getopt from moving all non-option arguments to the end of the command line" and the colon (:) "disables getopt from displaying error messages".

If a non-option argument is found, then getopt will return an integer value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and throw my answer in. I've tested it, and it complies with `getopt` as described [here on Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/3/optind). Note, this answer only allows **options first, then non-options after**. But this is normal for a lot of CLI tools.

I'm adding this answer now because I found the EDIT in the answer from Klas did not work.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    int c;
    
    // Process option arguments
    while (-1 != (c = getopt(argc, argv, "abc:"))) {
         switch (c) {
     case 'a': printf("option: a\n"); break;
     case 'b': printf("option: b\n"); break;
     case 'c': printf("option: c with arg: \"%s\"\n", optarg); break;
     default:
         printf("unknown arg: %2X\n", optopt);
     }
    }
    
    // Process remaining arguments
    for (int i = optind; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("non-option: %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```