# Mandatory parameter getopt in C

Tags: c, getopt

I have this piece of code in C

```
while((i = getopt(argc, argv, ":p:h:s:n:l:f:SLNF")) != -1)
    switch(i){
        case 'p': printf("Porta obbligatoria\n");
                  break;
        case 'h': printf("hostname\n");
                  break;
        case 's': printf("Surname\n");
                  break;
        case 'n': printf("Name\n");
                  break;
        case 'l': printf("Login\n");
                  break;
        case 'f': printf("Faculty\n");
                  break;
        case 'S': printf("Print Surname\n");
                  break;
        case 'L': printf("Print Login\n");
                  break;
        case 'N': printf("Print First name\n");
                  break;
        case 'F': printf("Print Faculty\n");
                  break;
        case '?': printf("USAGE\n");
                  break;
        default: printf("USAGE default\n");
                  break;


    }


   return 0;
}
```

How can I have only one mandatory parameter? In my case is p.

For example:

```
./MyProgram -p 80 -h 127.0.0.1
```

Result ok.

```
./MyProgram -h 127.0.0.1
```

Error because missing -p

Only -p.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using getopt in C with non-option arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079340/using-getopt-in-c-with-non-option-arguments)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually you use the while loop to store the values and then check the mandatory options after the loop:

```
    int p = -1;

    while((i = getopt(argc, argv, ":p:h:s:n:l:f:SLNF")) != -1)
        switch(i){
            case 'p': p = (int)atol(optarg);
                      break;
            <skipped a few options >
            default: printf("USAGE default\n");
                      break;
        }

    // Check mandatory parameters:
    if (p == -1) {
       printf("-p is mandatory!\n");
       exit 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use atol(). It has no error recovery and hasn't been suitable for new code for a long time. Use strtol() instead.

Comment: Don't use strtol, as it throws an exception which if not handled can ruin your code. Additionally exception safe programming ruins the structure of your code and turns the system into an absolutely horrendous mess.

Comment: @Owl: functions in C do not throw exceptions; there are no exceptions in C.

Comment: Error messages should be printed on `stderr`, not `stdout`.