# mandatory and optional options with argc and argv

Tags: c, argv, getopt, argc

I want to create a programme that will have mandatory option and optional option.

Mandatory:

- `-d <device>`

Optional:

- `-h : help`
- `-m <value>` : launch an internal function with the value of the argument.
- ... (other optional option with or without argument).

I see how manage only optional option but how to cohabitate the mandatory and optional?

Other info: the mandatory option will give the information on what /dev/video# to open and needs to be done before parsing the optional options where functions will be called that need to have the file descriptor already opened.

I tried to manage it with getopt() but I did not see how to manage both mandatory and optional options.

Comment: In your program logic, if you are not finding a "mandatory" option in the list of the options provided - generate an error.

Comment: This has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976495/mandatory-parameter-getopt-in-c

Comment: Read all of the option values first, then process them.

Comment: eone, "I tried to manage it with getopt()" ==>post your try here.