# Getopt function without options just arguments

Tags: c, getopt

I am not sure how to use the getopt command in my scenario.
I want the following input command:

```
mydiff file1 file2
```

So there are no options just the two filenames. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Is `getopt` required? You could just declare `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` and take the filenames from `argv[]`.

Comment: "*how to use the getopt command*" just don't. Use `main()`'s arguments directly.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18079340/694576

Answer (score 1):

If your program does not accept POSIX-style options, then alk has the right of it - you don't need `getopt()` if you have no options to get.

Per the getopt(3) manpage, once `getopt()` has exhausted the provided options (which, being *options,* may be zero in number), it returns `(int) -1` and sets `optind` to the index of the first non-opt argument in `argv[]` which, in your example, would be `argv[1] -> file1`.

Comment: OK I got it. How could I check if there are any options and if there really are I want to give out an error. At the moment I get an inavlid option message. I guess I could do if(getopt(argc,argv,"")!=-1) then error.

Comment: You could try that and see what happens, but I'm not aware of any stock Unix tools that explicitly check for unwanted _types_ of args. The most I've ever done in this sort of situation is something like `if (argc < MINARGS || argc > MAXARGS)` where `MAXARGS = 3` and `MINARGS = 3` (or `MINARGS = 1` if we can run as a filter.)